# No se encuentra servicio en el fichero WSDL - PowerBuilder

Tags: java, webservice, jboss, jboss-5.x, powerbuilder

Estamos tratando de consumir desde nuestra aplicación en PowerBuilder 10 un servicio web (*webservice*) que exponemos en un JBoss 5. Hemos probado consumir web services expuestos en JBoss 4 sin problemas, pero no estamos dando con la tecla de por qué no logra ver las operaciones de los WSDL de JBoss 5.

Cuando intentamos consumir un ws en JBoss 5, ést es el mensaje que nos da PowerBuilder:

> There is no service in the WSDL file

Por otro lado, lo que sí se ve es que el formato de los contratos entre un  JBoss y otro difiere: los tags de JBoss 4 están precedidos en su mayoría de `wsdl:` pero en fin... no hay mucha info por ahí y lograr esto nos evitaría seguir con las DLLs que tantos dolores de cabeza nos dan.

Comment: Hola @jurema. Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Te invito a que conozcas como funciona la comunidad visitando [esta presentación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y también te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta para que se ajuste a las políticas de calidad del sitio consultado la [guía para hacer una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hola @Jurema. ¿La misma aplicación desplegada en JBoss 4 es la que estás desplegando en JBoss 5? ¿Cómo accedes al archivo WSDL expuesto en tu servidor JBoss 4? ¿No funciona lo mismo cuando la aplicación se encuentra en JBoss 5? ¿Cómo han construido los servicios, utilizando Java EE puro o mediante algún framework como Apache CXF, Axis 2, Spring u otro?

Comment: Hola @toledano. Puse ese título porque es el mensaje que nos da powerbuilder cuando intentamos consumir un ws en JBoss 5. Y como tengo la costumbre de buscar netamente por el error pensé que sería una buena guía... Igualmente veo que ya está editada mi pregunta cumpliendo con sus estándares. Saludos.

Comment: Cambié el título y borré el mensaje de error. Lo pongo dentro de la pregunta para que esté visible.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza cómo estás? gracias por tu pronta respuesta y perdón por la demora. No es la misma aplicación, probamos con distintos WS levantados algunos en JBoss 4 y otros en JBoss 5. Si entendí bien tu pregunta. Usamos JAX-WS en ambos casos. ¿No funciona lo mismo cuando la aplicación se encuentra en JBoss 5? No comprendí muy bien esta. ¿Dices de probar levantar el WS de JBoss 5 en JBoss 4? Aparentemente fueron hechos con Apache Axis 1.4. Otro detalle es que algunos servicios en JBoss 4 no los reconoce tampoco.Saludos y muchas gracias!

Comment: Pensé que tu problema era que la misma aplicación no podía mostrar el WSDL en JBoss 5 cuando sí lo hace en JBoss 4. Pero es una aplicación diferente, por lo cual me parece más un problema de tu aplicación a que sea un problema en JBoss. Y sí, sería recomendable si pudieses levantar cada aplicación en cada servidor de aplicaciones para ver su comportamiento.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. Pruebo haciendo eso a ver qué nos dice. De todos modos la consulta venía porque la idea es ir dejando JBoss 4. Por eso ni consideramos probarla en JBoss 4. Saludos y gracias.